# Quick Release vs Thru-axle specifications when buying wheels

Tags: axle, quick-release, through-axle

I'm experiencing some confusion pertaining to axle choice as I'm attempting to purchase some wheels, if somebody in this forum could provide some clarification it would be greatly appreciated.

I just recently completed a bike build with a cyclocross frame, the Dengfu FM286 specifically:

http://dengfubikes.com/Cyclo_Cross/112.html

So far, I've been using wheels/tires from a 2017 Giant AnyRoad CoMax that I'm now going to leave as a backup/2nd bike.  The wheels are Giant PX-2 which are very heavy so I'm planning on replacing them with this:

https://www.yoeleobike.com/carbon-wheels-38mm-sat-c38-road-db-std.html

The Yoeleo 38 mm deep carbon clincher road 700C disc brake wheels, 25 mm wide.

I should mention that the Giant PX-2 quick-release wheels fit the FM286 frame perfectly.  I measured the distance between the inside of the drop-outs on both the 2017 CoMax and the FM286 at about 100 mm front, 135 mm rear, which I'm under the impression is the industry standard for traditional quick-release skewer type axles.

Now on to the source of confusion, which is the axle choice drop-down box on the above linked Yoeleo page, which offers the following options:

[image]

Scrolling down further under the "Description" section the following additional information is found:

[image]

I'm under the impression that "O.L.D." = Over-Lock-nut Distance, i.e. the width of the axle between the threads, which should correspond to the distance between the inside of the drop-outs on the frame.

I'm trying to figure out what the drop-down options mean and which is the correct choice in my case.  Here's my best guess as to an expanded explanation of the options in the drop-down (also using the information from the description section):

"QR / QR for Shimano/Sram 10,11s" means:

front axle is a traditional quick release (100 mm wide), rear axle is a traditional quick release (135 mm wide), compatible with Shimano or Sram 10 or 11 speed cassettes

"15mm / 135mm QR for Shimano/Sram 10,11s" means:

front axle is a thru-axle (15 mm diameter, 100 mm wide), rear axle is a traditional quick release (135 mm wide), compatible with Shimano or Sram 10 or 11 speed cassettes

"15mm / 142x12mm for Shimano/Sram 10,11s" means:

front axle is a thru-axle (15 mm diameter, 100 mm wide), rear axle is a thru-axle (12 mm diameter, 142 mm wide), compatible with Shimano or Sram 10 or 11 speed cassettes

"12mm / 142x12mm for Shimano/Sram 10,11s" means:

front axle is a thru-axle (12 mm diameter, 100 mm wide), rear axle is a thru-axle (12 mm diameter, 142 mm wide), compatible with Shimano or Sram 10 or 11 speed cassettes

"12mm / 135x12mm for Shimano/Sram 10,11s +$10" means:

front axle is a thru-axle (12 mm diameter, 100 mm wide), rear axle is a thru-axle (12 mm diameter, 135 mm wide), compatible with Shimano or Sram 10 or 11 speed cassettes, at $10 additional cost

Is my understanding correct?

Returning to my specific situation, I'd like to stick with traditional quick-release skewers at both the front and rear, and I used an 11 speed Shimano Ultegra rear derailleur with the FM286 build.

So, considering all of the above, I'm under the impression that the correct choice in my case would be the first axle option in the drop-down, "QR / QR for Shimano/Sram 10,11s", correct?

Can anybody confirm my understanding of the above?  If I'm incorrect in my interpretation anywhere, please clarify, thanks!

Comment: Great well written question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine my bike's fork width?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/56444/how-do-i-determine-my-bikes-fork-width)

Answer (score 1):

You have it correct. You basically need any QR disc road wheels. Note that 135 is the standard for QR disc rear ends but non-disc road is 130, and some other bike genres use other numbers.