# How do I determine my bike's fork width?

Tags: fork, trainer

I have a Breezer Liberty 2.3. I am trying to determine whether it would work with the [CycleOps Hammer](https://www.cycleops.com/product/hammer) trainer. The trainer says it is *"Quick-release compatible for bike frames with fork widths of 130mm and 135 mm."*, 
However, I am not sure how to measure that on my bike, and I can't figure it out by looking at the [specs page](http://www.breezerbikes.com/bikes/specs/liberty-2-3) for the bike.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quick Release vs Thru-axle specifications when buying wheels](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/46757/quick-release-vs-thru-axle-specifications-when-buying-wheels)

Comment: Drop the wheel out and put a ruler between the dropouts.   If you have a caliper then you might not even need to drop the wheel.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov Let's close the other question as a dupe on this one. The other question is incredibly long-winded and it's a huge amount of work to figure out what's going on when there's literally three screenfuls of question and the answer is "Yes, you're right." Here, we have a better question _and_ a better answer. **Please don't close this as a duplicate.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This refers to the interior distance between the rear wheel dropouts on the frame. The rear triangle is sometimes referred to as the frame 'fork', not to be confused with the front wheel fork.

The vast majority of modern bikes with quick release hubs have 100mm spaced front wheel dropouts and either 130 or 135mm rear wheel dropouts. If you measure the distance with the wheel out it may be a few mm off of 130 or 135mm as frames flex a bit when the quick release is undone.